# Debugging in Visual Studio 2012 is slow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

We have a large ASP.NET application that has been built over the last decade and is now running in .NET 4.0.

Recently, we upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 Premium (from 2010 Premium).
Our application compiles successfully, and when we run/debug our application its from a local IIS on each one of our developer workstations (versus using using the development server).

Ever since upgrading to 2012, when we are debugging our application, we have noticed the application to run VERY slow in loading ASP.NET pages, it can take nearly 20-30 seconds per page. But, when we access the application straight to the local IIS and without using the VS2012 debugger, it runs great. Something about debugging in Visual Studio 2012 on our application is slowing down our application performance significantly.

Is there a good tool we could use to capture what is going on in the background?

Also, this is happening on both Windows 7 Enterprise machines and Windows 8 Pro machines.  All 64 bit with 8+ GB of RAM, and Intel Core i7 processors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have set many breakpoints in the project?

Comment: can you try adding below setting in web.config?              <appSettings>
    <add key ="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled"></add>
</appSettings>

Answer (score 1):

My debug on VS 2012 was very slow, it was taking 20~30 seconds for every step.

My solution was disable the .NET Reflector extension.

Go to Tools - Extensions and Updates - Disable .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all breakpoints, then clean and rebuild solution and debug it again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application is throwing and catching lots of exceptions?  This can really slow things down in debug mode.  Set the Exceptions properties to break on CLR exceptions and see if this is the case.